# If syntax in Webi

Tags: business-objects, webi

I am trying to write a `if` condition in `webi`  but unable to accomplish.

Below is the code:

```
if ([Summary Column] inlist("a","b");"a")
```

Error I am getting

> Unrecognized input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are missing `;`. try using below code.

```
If ([Summary Column] InList("a";"b");"a")
```